# import variable module object from module in js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, module

I want to import a module object from a module, but I don't know in advance which objects i will need. How can I use a variable in the module names section?

```
import { variable } from './module'
```

variable is what I want to import based on what the user will perform on the website.

I tried:

```
const variable = moduleObject
import { variable } from './module'
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as everything from './module'

everything[variable]
```

Comment: there is thousands of modules objects in the module, it would not be efficient to do it like this I guess, I try to have a more optimised way of doing it without having to load thousands of objects. if it exists